# For what values of $x \in\mathbb R$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^5+n^2x^3}{x^4+n^4}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> For what values of $x \in\mathbb R$ does this series converge? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^5+n^2x^3}{x^4+n^4}$$
>
> Also, on what subset of $\mathbb R$ does it define a continuous function?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

For $n\ge x$,

$$\left|\frac{x^5+x^3n^2}{x^4+n^4}\right|\le |x^3|\frac{2n^2}{n^4} $$

and the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure.

Comment: Are you assuming $ n \ge |x|$? And how do you make sure there's no other value (such that x > n) for which the series converges? Thank you!

Comment: $n$ runs from $1$ to $\infty$.  So, for any fixed $x$, however large, there will be some integer $N$ for which $N\ge x$.  Then, for all of the remaining $n>N$, we have $n>N\ge x$.

Comment: Pleased to hear.  Well done.